# Trying to make a grid with nested UIStack views programatically

Tags: ios, swift

I wanted to create "GridView" that would always fit to the size of its parent view. So my idea was this:

- Have a vertical stack view be the main container.
- Inside the vertical stack view will be rows of horizontal stack views.
- As a filler, I would just add buttons to the rows of the horizontal stack views.

So the general rundown on how it would be initialized is this:

1. Initialize vertical stack view and set its constraints to equal the leading, trailing, width, and height anchor of its parent view.
2. Based off of the given dimensions of the grid (AxB), create **A** horizontal stack rows and **B** buttons inside those horizontal rows.

   - Set the constraints of each horizontal stack to equal the leading, trailing, width, and height of its parent view **(main container stack view)**.
3. Set the autoresizingMask of each buttons to flexibleWidth and flexibleHeight.

This is my current logic so far for the initialization of the "GridView" which I'm using for my implementation. Now the main *issue* I'm having is that instead of the horizontal stack views being vertically stacked, it actually just ends up being overlapped on top of each other.

(1x1) 
[Overlap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMgdb.png)

If I add the buttons *just* to the main container, it will stack vertically without a problem.

(1x1) 
[Vertical Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZamA.png)

It seems like  putting a horizontal stack inside a vertical stack causes the issue. Any thoughts and suggestions? I've thought about just using the table view to create a grid but **this issue has gotten me curious and I really want to know why its happening.**

Here's my code implementation:

```
func createGrid(x: Int, y: Int, rootView: UIView) {
    //Init stack view.
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.alignment = .fill
    stackView.distribution = .fillEqually


    for i in (1...x) {
        let hStackView = UIStackView()
        hStackView.axis = .horizontal
        hStackView.alignment = .fill
        hStackView.distribution = .fillEqually

        for _ in (1...y) {
            let button = WordBoxView()
            button.setTitle("\(i)", for: .normal)
            hStackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
        }

        let button = WordBoxView()
        button.setTitle("\(i)", for:.normal)
        hStackView.addArrangedSubview(button)

        //Add horizontal row stack to vertical parent stack.
        stackView.addSubview(hStackView)
        fitParentLayout(hStackView, parentView: stackView)
    }

    rootView.addSubview(stackView)

    //setup stack view bounds
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    fitParentLayout(stackView, parentView: rootView)
}

func fitParentLayout(_ child: UIView, parentView: UIView) {

    child.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        parentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: child.leadingAnchor),
        parentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: child.trailingAnchor),
        parentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: child.widthAnchor),
        parentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: child.heightAnchor)])
}
```

Comment: I think you can do this with collection view, did you try?

Comment: You really should not be using `addSubview` to add `UIStackView` subviews, i.e. use `addArrangedSubview` to add the `hStackView` to the vertical stack view. Also, don't add constraints (no need to use `fitParentLayout` to add the horizontal stack view to the vertical one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **I found 2 problem in your code:**
>
> 1. You have added `leading, trailing, width` and `height` constraints, but it will not determine your view's y-origin. So assign `top`. (leading and trailing would determine width automatically so no need to give width constraints)
> 2. You just need to give constraints to outer `UIStackView`, inner stack view will take the frames automatically according to outer stack view's properties.

**Update your code as:**

```
func createGrid(x: Int, y: Int, rootView: UIView) {
    //Init stack view.
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.alignment = .fill
    stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    stackView.spacing = 10
    
    for i in 1...x {
        let hStackView = UIStackView()
        hStackView.axis = .horizontal
        hStackView.alignment = .fill
        hStackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        hStackView.spacing = 10
        
        for _ in 1...y {
            let button = UIButton()
            button.backgroundColor = .red
            button.setTitle("\(i)", for: .normal)
            hStackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
        }

        //Add horizontal row stack to vertical parent stack.
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(hStackView)
    }
    
    rootView.addSubview(stackView)
    
    //setup stack view bounds
    fitParentLayout(stackView, parentView: rootView)
}


func fitParentLayout(_ child: UIView, parentView: UIView) {
    child.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        parentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: child.leadingAnchor),
        parentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: child.trailingAnchor),
        parentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: child.topAnchor),
        parentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: child.heightAnchor)])
}
```

Comment: This worked, in fitParentLayout() instead of parentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: child.heightAnchor)]) I used parentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: child.bottomAnchor)]).

Answer (score 1):

You said

> Set the constraints of each horizontal stack to equal the leading, trailing, width, and height of its parent view (main container stack view).

You don't want the height of a row (horizontal stack view) to equal the height of the main container stack view. Setting that height constraint is probably the cause of your woes.

Remove this constraint:

```
parentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: child.heightAnchor)
```

You also don't need the parent/child width constraint, but that one is harmless.

Comment: You're correct, I was using the wrong constraints and I didn't realize that. I adjusted my code to match @DonMag suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of "whoops" mistakes...

At the end of your `for i in (1...x)` loop:

```
   //Add horizontal row stack to vertical parent stack.
   stackView.addSubview(hStackView)
```

should be:

```
   //Add horizontal row stack to vertical parent stack.
   stackView.addArrangedSubview(hStackView)
```

and, you don't need (and shouldn't do) the following line

```
   fitParentLayout(hStackView, parentView: stackView)
```

because you are using the `.alignment` and `.distribution` of the vertical stack view to control the sizes / positions  of the child horizontal stack views.

And, your `fitParentLayout()` has the views swapped. It should be:

```
func fitParentLayout(_ child:UIView, parentView:UIView)
{
    child.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        child.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.leadingAnchor),
        child.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.trailingAnchor),
        child.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.topAnchor),
        child.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.bottomAnchor)])
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: Ah, I should've been using topAnchor and bottomAnchor instead of the width and height anchor constraints.